# Connect to oneDrive with C# in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, onedrive

I have a C# Windows Forms application and I want to upload an XML file to OneDrive and download it to my application.

I read MSDN about the `Microsoft.Live` libraries, but I could not find anything, or at least I did not understand what should I do. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Please reefer below sample code which helps you to connect one drive and access its files and folders.

```
            var optConfig = new Options
            {
                ClientId = "0000000000000000",
                ClientSecret = "XXXXt02UYkQm6Kb48fKtD7",
                CallbackUrl = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf",
                AutoRefreshTokens = true,
                PrettyJson = false,
                AccessToken = "AccessTokenXXXXX",
                RefreshToken = "RefreshTokenXXXX",
                ReadRequestsPerSecond = 2,
                WriteRequestsPerSecond = 2
            };

            var client = new Client(optConfig);

            var rootFolder = await client.GetFolderAsync();
            // rootFolder.Name - folder name
            //rootFolder.Id  - folder id

            var folderContent = await client.GetContentsAsync(rootFolder.Id);

            foreach (var item in folderContent)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tItem ({0}: {1} (Id: {2})", item.Type, item.Name, item.Id);
                var folderContent = await client.GetContentsAsync(item.Id);
                var filesList = folderContent.Where(e => e.Type != "folder");
                                foreach (var fileItem in filesList)
                                {
                                   //Download files here
                                    var uri = fileItem.Source;
                                    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                                    HttpWebResponse response;
                                    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();                                      
                                    if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
                                         response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
                                         response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect))
                                    {
                                        var tempFileName = response.ResponseUri.Segments[(response.ResponseUri.Segments.Count() - 1)];
                                        using (var fileStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                                        {
                                        //Save Strame   
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
            }
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer.

Comment: The question was posted over 4 years ago, and is off-topic as "too broad" (just a requirement, without any programming question) and also a tool/resource/tutorial recommendation question (asking for offsite resources for help). Best not to answer such a question (as Stack Overflow really isn't set up to have people post requirements and have others code up solutions).